# What does this simple If-Statement do?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm not a programmer (beginning to learn Python).

Please help me understand this psuedocode:

```
     {
  if ( !*(sub_676578() + 2644) )
  {
    EnterCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
    ++dw_FrameCounter;
    if ( !b_AnimFlag )
    {
      if ( !b_PauseFlag )
      {
        dw_TFraction += 1092;
        if ( dw_TFraction >> 16 )
        {
          ++dw_TSeconds;
          dw_TFraction = dw_TFraction;
        }
        dw_CDFraction += 1092;
        if ( dw_CDFraction >> 16 )
        {
          if ( b_TimerDirection & 2 )
          {
            ++dw_CDSeconds;
          }
          else
          {
            if ( dw_CDSeconds )
              --dw_CDSeconds;
          }
          dw_CDFraction = dw_CDFraction;
        }
      }
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&CriticalSection);
  }
}
```

I specifically don't understand the 'IF' lines.
I also don't understand why `dword_DC08C0 = dword_DC08C0;` exists

EDIT: If you wish to see the entire function, it is here: http://pastie.org/8306763

Comment: I don't think that code is going to be of much help to you in learning Python. Or anything else, really.

Comment: seems like your code is broken, some texts missing.

Comment: The pseudo-code is C-like. So `if` checks for a non-zero value. If the value is non-zero, the `if` branch is taken (true). If the value is zero, then the `if` branch is not taken (false). The `!byte_DC0E70` is a "not byte_DC0E70" so it's the opposite: if `byte_DC0E70` is zero, `if` branch is taken. Otherwise not.

Comment: Line 7 looks like a mistake.

Comment: Well that's some bizarre code - but line 1 means that if the value of variable byte_DC0E70 is 0 - ie not (!) 1.  and line 4 - if fraction / 65536 is non zero - where 0 if false and non zero is true.  Where did you dredge this code up from.

Comment: This isn't Python - so what Python book did you grab this from?

Comment: The OP did say it was "psuedocode", so it not being valid syntax for a language isn't surprising.

Comment: `dword_DC08C0 = dword_DC08C0;` cool

Comment: @mp3ferret this is automatically decompiled code from IDA debugger. The software decompiled from the raw ASM. So perhaps that's why there are weird lines?

Comment: @user2071506 - Phew, I'm glad it didn't come out of a person ;)

Comment: @mp3ferret so what should I do if I manually look through the disasm and find this weird line? I should assume it is a programmer's mistake? :)

Comment: @mbratch thanks this is exactly what I did not understand!

Comment: You should assume that the output of a decompiler is essentially useless, particularly for learning to program, particularly if you are trying to learn python, but really just in general.

Comment: line 4'd changed - so thats an if ( the value of dword_DC08C0 where the bits are shifted right by 16 bits is = to non zero (or true).  so essentially if there any bits set in the most significant 16 bits of the dword (32 bits)

Comment: @Ben actually this decompiler is very useful! :P It has given me a lot of information so far that has helped me in my project. Just I don't understand the simple If-Statements.

Comment: Hard to say what a decompiler saw to make it generate "x = x". I wouldn't assume that the original was any kind of error. It probably started out high level, got compiled, then got decompiled. You may see strange things that are not an "error" but don't do anything useful.

Comment: @mbratch thank you. I will take this information on board as I probe deepr into this function :)

Comment: What did you to consider it's as "simple if-statement"? it's an example of obfuscated code, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code can be converted to a more human-readable form:

```
if ( byte_DC0E70 == 0 )
{
   dword_DC08C0 += 1092;
   if ( ( dword_DC08C0 / 65536 ) != 0 )
   {
      dword_DC08B8 += 1;
      dword_DC08C0 = dword_DC08C0;
   }   
}
```

Further interpretation is complicated by the absence of any context.

Comment: DC08C0 = fractions of a timer.
DC08B8 = seconds of a timer.

It seems it adds 1 second to the timer when the fractions are over 65535

Comment: as this has come out of a decompiler is it not just a generated name for a variable.

Comment: @mp3ferret nope, it is the RAM location. If I open a RAM view program I can navigate to 00DC08B8 and there I see the Timer (in seconds)

Comment: Is it inside some function? What is just before and after this piece of code? Where else are these variables used?

Comment: 1092/65536 = 1/60th. This program uses 1/60th of seconds? It's more likely to be the second or minute counter instead.

Comment: @user2071506 and it does make me wonder if `dword_DC08C0 = dword_DC08C0;` should really be `dword_DC08C0 &= 0xFFFF;` but hard to tell without further context.

Comment: @mbratch: agreed, that at least makes sense for this tiny snippet of code. It looks like a copy-paste error; perhaps the OP re-typed it instead of copying.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, the game runs at 60 fps. It adds 1092 fractions per frame. :)

Comment: @user2071506: ``if ( byte_DC093B & 2 ) { ... } else { ... };``

Comment: @mbratch Hey! I dug into the ASM manually, and you are exactly right. The decompiler must've made a mistake. The ASM clearly shows 'AND 0xFFFF'