# Manual Decompilation References

Tags: c++, c, assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm looking for book titles or papers about how to decompile X86 Disassembly into C/C++ code MANUALLY.
Well , I know about many tools that do the job , but I think doing it manually is more efficient even if it's a slow process.

Comment: I don't think doing it manually can possible be more efficient! It will be a slow and painful process even with an intimate knowledge of the compiler and assembler. It might be a good idea to start with through to get a good insight into the code production process.

Comment: It's not even possible to do what you're asking. Essentially (and ideally) you'll end up writing a brand new piece of code that happens to work the same way as the machine code you're sourcing it on. Decompilers take a large number of common scenarios to come up with a good guess what the source was - can you remember hundreds of those and use them faster than a decompiler??

Comment: I dont agree with these answers.  It depends on your assembly skills.  You cannot and will not recover the original C code, but you can certainly examine assembly and create C code that is functionally the same.  No different than converting any language to any language (that differs by quite a bit in syntax).  The larger the process the longer it will take but it is not a complicated process, in general.

Comment: See [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677230/what-does-this-simple-if-statement-do) for a discussion on what *appears* to be a complicated function, but turned out not to be (even though it contained a "disassembly error").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are VERY used to looking at disassembly from a particular compiler, you MAY be able to come up with decent C or C++ code. But it's a TERRIBLY slow process even then. Just taking one small function (say a for-loop, a couple of if-statements and some basic math) and reconstructing it back into source code can take half an hour for me, and I don't think I'm terribly bad at it. Of course, one of the main points is identifying commonly used algorithms, such as linked lists, binary trees, string management, vector management, etc.

Doing it by machine will give you a lot of the work done for you, but even then, it can take days to do even a few hundred lines of orginal C++ code into something that is actually readable.